# Determine if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, computational-geometry

I've been fiddling around with some easy code challenges and there's one about determining if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene.

I've come up with a working solution, but I feel this could be greatly improved and/or simplified.

The sides of a triangle come in a list e.g. [2, 2, 2] or [0, 0, 0].

Here's what I've got.

```
def is_triangle(sides):
    if min(sides) <= 0:
        return False
    if sum(sorted(sides)[:-1]) < sorted(sides)[-1]:
        return False
    return True


def equilateral(sides):
    triangle = is_triangle(sides)
    if triangle:
        x, y, z = sides
        return x == y == z
    else:
        return False


def isosceles(sides):
    triangle = is_triangle(sides)
    if triangle:
        x, y, z = sides
        return x == y or y == z or z == x
    else:
        return False


def scalene(sides):
    if equilateral(sides) or isosceles(sides):
        return False
    return is_triangle(sides)
```

Also, I'm adding a simple unit test module.

```
import unittest

from triangle import equilateral, isosceles, scalene

class TestEquilateralTriangle(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_all_sides_are_equal(self):
        self.assertIs(equilateral([2, 2, 2]), True)

    def test_all_zero_sides_is_not_a_triangle(self):
        self.assertIs(equilateral([0, 0, 0]), False)

    def test_third_triangle_inequality_violation(self):
        self.assertIs(isosceles([3, 1, 1]), False)

    def test_sides_may_be_floats(self):
        self.assertIs(equilateral([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]), True)


class TestIsoscelesTriangle(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_last_two_sides_are_equal(self):
        self.assertIs(isosceles([3, 4, 4]), True)

    def test_equilateral_triangles_are_also_isosceles(self):
        self.assertIs(isosceles([4, 4, 4]), True)

    def test_third_triangle_inequality_violation(self):
        self.assertIs(isosceles([3, 1, 1]), False)

    def test_sides_may_be_floats(self):
        self.assertIs(isosceles([0.5, 0.4, 0.5]), True)


class TestScaleneTriangle(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_no_sides_are_equal(self):
        self.assertIs(scalene([5, 4, 6]), True)

    def test_all_sides_are_equal(self):
        self.assertIs(scalene([4, 4, 4]), False)

    def test_third_triangle_inequality_violation(self):
        self.assertIs(isosceles([3, 1, 1]), False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I'd appreciate some feedback on my code.

Comment: Similar challenge: [_Determine whether three sides form a valid triangle, and classify the triangle_](/q/224810).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A triangle has, by definition, three sides. I find it therefore weird to take a single `sides` argument, which could be of any size. This opens you up to obscure bugs, such as these ones, which are not covered in your tests:

```
>>> is_triangle([1,2,3,4])
True    # ?
>>> is_triangle([1, 1])
True    # ???
>>> is_triangle([float('nan')])
True    # WTF?
```

Instead, just explicitly take three arguments. The sides of a triangle are customarily called `a, b, c`.

```
def is_triangle(a, b, c):
    a, b, c = sorted([a, b, c])
    return a > 0 and a + b > c
```

This uses the fact that after the `sorted`, `a` is always the smallest side, as [mentioned in the comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224878/determine-if-a-triangle-is-equilateral-isosceles-or-scalene/224904?noredirect=1#comment436476_224904).

The only thing you need to change in your calling code is to call this with `is_triangle(*sides)`, i.e. use tuple unpacking.

---

Your other functions can also be shortened a bit. Try to put multiple checks in one line to `return` right away (but don't push it if it gets too complicated).

```
def equilateral(a, b, c):
    return is_triangle(a, b, c) and a == b == c
```

Instead of manually checking all combinations of sides for equality, just use `set` to get rid of multiples:

```
def isosceles(a, b, c):
    return is_triangle(a, b, c) and len(set([a, b, c])) <= 2

def scalene(a, b, c):
    return is_triangle(a, b, c) and len(set([a, b, c])) == 3
```

---

Note that all functions need to use `is_triangle`. You could define a decorator that makes sure the input is a triangle:

```
from functools import wraps

def ensure_triangle(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(a, b, c):
        return is_triangle(a, b, c) and func(a, b, c)
    return wrapper

@ensure_triangle
def equilateral(a, b, c):
    return a == b == c

@ensure_triangle
def scalene(a, b, c):
    return len(set([a, b, c])) == 3

@ensure_triangle
def isosceles(a, b, c):
    return len(set([a, b, c])) <= 2
```

Comment: One other change I would suggest is renaming those methods to start with `is_` for consistency and clarity. I really like the use of a decorator here.

Answer (score 6):

After a *very* quick pass, here's what I have for you:

I assumed `... sorted(sides)[-1]:` was a typo, so I removed the `:`.

- **Return Expressions**: It's better to return expressions than to just `else: return False`. Returning the expression that is evaluated saves time, and looks cleaner.
- **Docstrings**: I'm  a stickler for docstrings. Even if the method is blatantly obvious about its function, you should still include a docstring. Keeps you in the practice for when you start writing bigger programs that require more detail.

***Final Code***

```
def is_triangle(sides):
    """ Determines if the list passed is a triangle """
    return False if min(sides) <= 0 or sum(sorted(sides)[:-1]) < sorted(sides)[-1] else True

def equilateral(sides):
    """ Determines if the list passed is an equilateral triangle """
    if is_triangle(sides):
        x, y, z = sides
        return x == y == z
    return False


def isosceles(sides):
    """ Determines if the list passed is an isosceles triangle """
    if is_triangle(sides):
        x, y, z = sides
        return x == y or y == z or z == x
    return False


def scalene(sides):
    """ Determines if the list passed is a scalene triangle """
    return False if equilateral(sides) or isosceles(sides) else is_triangle(sides)
```

Comment: I find your `is_triangle()` implementation awkward. It would be clearer to write `return min(sides) > 0 and sum(sorted(sides)[:-1])) > sorted(sides)[-1]`

Comment: The `return False if ...` ternary in scalene is missing an else. Also surely it would be easier to use `not expr` instead of the pattern `False if expr else True`

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) to keep the tests close to the code and more readable.  For example:

```
def equilateral(sides):
    '''
    True if the 'sides' argument represents an equilateral triangle
    (all sides of equal length).

    >>> equilateral([2, 2, 2])
    True
    >>> equilateral([0, 0, 0])
    False
    >>> isosceles([3, 1, 1])
    False
    >>> equilateral([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    True
    '''
    x, y, z = sides
    return is_triangle(sides) and x == y == z
```

(er, why was that `isosceles()` test in `TestEquilateralTriangle`?  Is that a copy-paste error?)

Then we can easily run all the tests:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```